# Toggle nav not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The website is http://109.74.0.128/~app/assistanstv/assistanstv/www.assistans.tv/tv.html

HTML:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="active">
        <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Barnasisstans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intervjuer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Juridik</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LSS2020</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Utbildning</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
    </nav>
```

jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

the css code is too long, i cant get it work anyway. This drive me soon crazy. Whats wrong?!

Edit: Problem solved. The problem was

it was a / in the end. I solved it by deleted the last /

Comment: fix other error in your script first

Comment: getting error TypeError: t.items[0] is undefined

Comment: you got any error?

Comment: This is the error people are getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDetails' of undefined` in file `(youmax-pro.min.js:13)` . This error prevents your code from running.

Comment: Hmmm? i've no idea.... how do i fix this?

Comment: What do you actually want. Do you want the link to be red on click?

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
            $('.toggle-nav').removeClass('active')
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
  background:tomato;
}
```

this class just a sample for showing toggling of class

[updatelink of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/54e3brap/)